# Python multiprocessing with fortran library

Tags: python, multiprocessing, f2py

I am using the multiprocessing module in Python to map a set of jobs onto as many cores as I have. The jobs I am wrapping are mostly performed with some wrapped fortran code (wrapped with f2py). When I call the jobs only, they go through fine using all cores. However, if I try to call the fortran library independently (not through the `Pool().map()` function) *firstly*, and *then* call the map, the whole program hangs (if you want to know, it hangs precisely at line 339 of threading.py on which the only code is `waiter.acquire()`).

For the program I am writing, I need to call the library before I go and map it. I have gotten around this by calling it firstly using `Pool().map()` with just a single process, but this is a hack, and I'd like to know why I am having to do this!

To be more explicit, this **does not** work:

```
def call_camb_transfer(H0): #wraps the call to define the keyword parameter to pass
    return pycamb.transfers(H0=H0)[1][6, :, 0]

b = call_camb_transfer(70)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
H0 = [60, 70]

results = pool.map(call_camb_transfer, H0)
```

but this does:

```
def call_camb_transfer(H0): #wraps the call to define the keyword parameter to pass
    return pycamb.transfers(H0=H0)[1][6, :, 0]

initial_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
b = initial_pool.map(call_camb_transfer, [65.0])

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
H0 = [60, 70]

results = pool.map(call_camb_transfer, H0)
```

where `pycamb` is the python wrapper of CAMB, which is a fortran library.